# how to activate enemies when there is a certain distance from player and enemy,and enemy is generated prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

it works if i place enemy in starting zone but it doesn't if its generated with environment in 2d game.

distance between enemy and player function

```
private float Distance()
    {
        return Vector3.Distance(Enemy.position, Player.position);
    }
```

if distance is less than 10 unit activate.

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Distance() < 10f)
        {
            if (!attack)
            {
                // IF NOT ATTACKING TURN ON RUN ANIMATION ,WITH SET SPEED 
                //print("Finding player");
                animator.SetTrigger(movementAnimationString);
                SetMovementSpeed(m_Speed);
                animator.SetBool("IsAttacking", attack);

            }
            // enemy is next to player and should attack BY ACTIVATING ATTACK ANIMATION
            else
            {
                SetMovementSpeed(0.0f);
                animator.SetTrigger(attackAnimationString);
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said it only works on enemies manually placed in the hierarchy but not for those generated.

Comment: Please provide information on how you link Enemy and Player when A) you place them manually and B) when you spawn them.

Comment: Hey :) . Are you familiar with `sqrMagnitude()`

Comment: Not enough information in the question to know for sure (please see how to include a [mre]) but I'm guessing that `Player` does not contain (if it is a field) or does not return (if it is a property) a useful reference because you neglect to assign something when you instantiate the prefab.

Comment: move this logic to enemies and use 'find' method to get the player object